# No se como hacer para que el histograma me salga horizontal

Tags: java

llevo dandole vueltas de como hacerlo, pero no me sale nada, alguien me podria explicar como podria hacerlo?

Muchas gracias.
Aqui el ejercicio que tengo que hacer y lo tengo hecho:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // 10. Un histograma es una gráfica que muestra la frecuencia con que aparecen en una lista dada los
    //      distintos valores que la pudieran formar. Realiza un histograma con valores comprendidos entre
    //      0 y 9. Por ejemplo, si la lista está formada por: 6, 4, 4, 1, 9, 7, 5, 6, 4, 2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 4, su
    //      histograma sería:
    //                 *
    //                 *   *
    //                 * * *     *
    //           * * * * * * *   *
    //         0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    //      Esto indica que 0 y 8 no aparecen ninguna vez, que 1, 2, 3 y 7 aparecen una vez, 5 y 9 dos
    //      veces, etc. Escriba un algoritmo que lea una lista de números comprendidos entre 0 y 9 (la lista
    //      acabará cuando se lea un número negativo) e imprima por pantalla un histograma como el anterior.

    /*  Procedimientos:
     *      1-          
     * 
     */

    int num;

    System.out.println("Cantidad de elementos: ");
    num = leerInt(); // Almacenamos cantidad de elementos

    int valor[] = new int[num]; // Creamos el vector

    for (int i = 0; i < valor.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("Que numero quieres meter en array %d: %n",i);
        num = leerInt();
        valor[i] = num;
    }

    histograma(valor); // Mostramos el histograma

}


public static void histograma(int[] v) { // Hace el histograma
    int count=0, count2=0;
    boolean pasar=false;


    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<v.length; j++) {
            //System.out.printf("  ");
            if(v[j]==i) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(count>count2) {
            count2=count;
        }
        count=0;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<v.length; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<10; j++){
            for (int k=0; k<v.length; k++) {
                if(v[k]==j) {
                count++;
                    if(count==count2&&pasar) {
                        System.out.printf("* ");
                        count=0;
                        if (count2>0) {
                            count2--;
                            pasar=false;
                        }else {
                            count2++;
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
            System.out.printf("  ");
            pasar=true;
        }
        System.out.println("");
        count=0;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%d ",i);
    }
}
```

Aqui lo que me hace el codigo y no se que puede estar pasando:

```
Cantidad de elementos: 
15
Que numero quieres meter en array 0: 
6
Que numero quieres meter en array 1: 
4
Que numero quieres meter en array 2: 
4
Que numero quieres meter en array 3: 
1
Que numero quieres meter en array 4: 
9
Que numero quieres meter en array 5: 
7
Que numero quieres meter en array 6: 
5
Que numero quieres meter en array 7: 
6
Que numero quieres meter en array 8: 
4
Que numero quieres meter en array 9: 
2
Que numero quieres meter en array 10: 
3
Que numero quieres meter en array 11: 
9
Que numero quieres meter en array 12: 
5
Que numero quieres meter en array 13: 
6
Que numero quieres meter en array 14: 
4
        *             
      *   *             
  *                   












0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Madre mia, ya veo yo aqui que la gente ayuda poco, solo dais a negativo cuando solo pido ayuda, me voy a la parte de ingles que creo que sera mas agradable...

Comment: Bienvenido.. mira por favor [ask]. Que es lo que buscas exactamente? intentaste algo? lo principal cuando se hacen ejercicios es que intentes algo, te traves, y vengas para que te ayudemos. No se que tipo de ayuda esperas... lo que hace ahi es contar cada numero y despues mostrarlo en esa grafica. Podes probar en ingles, pero te aseguro que va a terminar cerrada mucho mas rapido de lo que pensas...

Comment: @gbianchi Te comento amigo, lo que no se es como hacerlo en horizontal, como realizar el histograma de forma que lo haga como he puesto en la pregunta. He preguntado algo basico, estoy atascado en hacer un histograma, osea no se que tipo de preguna esta mal planteada la verdad.

Comment: @gbianchi ahi lo edito en la pregunta lo que tengo hecho. Se hacerlo vertical que es facil, pero horizontal ni idea

Comment: @gbianchi Pues mira te comento, de mi algoritmo me sale las veces que se repite un numero asi:

0:**
1:****

yo lo quisiera que salieran todos pero en vertical, tal y como esta puesto en la pregunta de arriba.

Muchisimas gracias por al menos tener el detalle de responder

Comment: @gbianchi editado

Comment: @gbianchi pues voy a intentar sacar el algoritmo por mi mismo, soy una persona muy cabezota y no me gusta que me resuelvan nada a no ser que este muy estresado, la cuestion si me resuelves el algoritmo con palabras seria de agradecer, ya que no quisiera verlo en el codigo, de todos modos, como podria hacerlo? por que dijiste algo de mayor a menor y no entendi muy bien

Comment: @gbianchi asi es, quiero que se muestre horizontal, voy a intentarlo 20 minutos mas, si no doy con la solucion, te pedire el algoritmo.

Comment: @gbianchi Lo he intentado de varias formas y solo consigo de imprimir 1 numero pero ya esta, no consigo de imprimir los demas, no me sale el algoritmo adecuado, podrias pasarmelo?

Comment: mostra como haces para imprimir un numero. el algoritmo y la salida...

Comment: @gbianchi edito el primer post.

Comment: @gbianchi viste el algoritmo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pude hacer lo que buscas solo que en orden inverso, para realizarlo utilice un HashMap donde el key es el numero (del 0 al 9) y el value es el numero de veces que se repite la key. Despues solo hice un while que va recorriendo el hashmap de 0 a 9 el numero de veces que se deba imprimir el asterisco. Te dejo el codigo a continuación:

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
    int valor;
    boolean stop = false;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
      System.out.print("Numero: ");
      valor = scan.nextInt();
      if(valor > 0) {
        nums.add(valor);
      } else {stop=true;}
    } while(!stop);
    scan.close();
    histograma( nums.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray() ); // Mostramos el histograma
  }

  public static void histograma(int[] v) { // Hace el histograma
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> clearList = new HashMap<>();
    int nv, rt=0;
    for(int i : v) {
      nv = clearList.containsKey(i) ? clearList.get(i) + 1 : 1;
      clearList.put(i, nv);
      rt++;
    }
    do {
      for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        if(clearList.containsKey(i) && clearList.get(i) > 0) {
          nv = clearList.get(i) - 1;
          clearList.put(i, nv);
          System.out.print("* ");
          rt--;
        } else {System.out.print("  ");}
      }
      System.out.println();
    }while(rt>0);
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
      System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

Versión online: https://repl.it/@JessHilario/Histograma-Horizontal

Salida:

```
  * * * * * * *   *
        * * *     *
        *   *
        *
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Como dije, solo busca como invertir el orden. Puedes guardar cada salida en un array y luego imprimir el array en orden inverso. Eso pude funcionar.

Espero te sirva!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, voy a realizar el codigo a la inversa a ver que tal funciona y ahora lo comento.

Answer (score 1):

Pues muchas gracias por tu ayuda @Jesús_Magallón al final pregunte al profesor y lo explico como podriamos hacerlo y este es el resultado. Espero que si alguien de mi clase lo ve, que no copie mi codigo, tan solo aprenda como yo intente hacer.

```
    import static proyectoTeclado.Teclado.*;

public class Ejercicio10 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num=1,max=0;
        int valor[]=new int[10];
        boolean stop=false;

        while(!stop) {
            System.out.println("Introduce numero: ");
            num=leerInt();
            if(num>=0&&num<=9) {
                valor[num]++;
                if(valor[num]>max) {
                    max=valor[num];
                }
            }else if(num>9) {
                System.out.println("Introduce solo entre 0 o 9, si quieres parar pon un numero negativo.");
            }else {
                stop=true;
            }
        }

        histograma(valor,max);

    }


    public static void histograma(int[] v, int max) { // Hace el histograma

        for(int i=max; i>0; i--) {
            for(int j=0; j<v.length; j++) {
                if(v[j]>=i) {
                    System.out.print("* ");

                }else {
                    System.out.print("  ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d ",i);
        }

    }

}
```

Salida:

```
        *           
        *   *       
        * * *     * 
  * * * * * * *   * 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Excelente!, al final tu solución es mucho más simple y más optima. Saludos!

Comment: @JesúsMagallón Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, la profesora me lo explico en clase y cogi el concepto de como hacerlo y una vez me lo explico, solo tarde 5 minutos en hacerlo, mas facil de lo que me pensaba. Saludos!